# Como disponibilizar uma aplicação MVC 6 (AspNet 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

trabalhei com asp.net durante um tempo e não tenho muito conhecimento na parte de infra-estrutura, sempre publiquei meus apps pelo visual studio e depois no servidor, adicionava uma nova aplicação pelo IIS, só que tudo isso mudou no ASP.NET 5 (Vnext), a minha dúvida é como posso disponibilizar um link para que meus clientes acessem.

Comment: sera hospedado interna ou externamente

Comment: Seria externamente

Answer (score 1):

**UM DOS MÉTODOS ABAIXO :**

- 1 - Utilize o IIS, coloque a aplicação na pasta C:\inetpub
- 2 - vá no seu roteador, e aponte a porta 80 para o ip da sua maquina
  ( para descobrir seu ip, abra o cmd, e digite ipconfig, e verifique a
  linha ipv4 ) suponde que seu ip interno da sua maquina seja
  192.168.1.100, entao voce vai aponta a porta 80 para esse ip.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- 3 - verifique qual é seu ip externoo site www.meuip.com.br  mostra
  qual é seu ip externo.
- 4 - supondo que seu ip externo seja 999.999.999.999, entao você vai
  passar assim para o cliente 999.999.999.999:80, e ele conseguira
  acessar sua aplicação.

DETALHE IMPORTANTE, SE SEU IP FOR DINAMICO, TERÁ QUE VERIFICAR SEMPRE QUAL É O SEU IP ANTES DE DISPONIBILIZAR PARA O IP PARA O CLIENTE
qualquer coisa estamos aqui .. :D